Desabafo sobre este site
Isso não era uma comunidade para ajudar? Então por que é tão difícil de fazer parte dela?
Não importa onde se estude, todo mundo sempre fala sobre este site e como ele é bom para obter ajuda, blabla.
Só que a realidade para um novato aqui não é bem essa. Estou me dedicando firme a estudar programação há 3 meses e durante esse tempo tive inúmeras dúvidas. Realmente, já resolvi algumas delas aqui, mas essas foram a exceção.
Já faz tempo que evito entrar aqui para perguntar algo, porque sei que é sempre a mesma decepção e desânimo. Dá para contar nos dedos às vezes que consegui algo daqui. Não há empatia com quem está começando, essa questão de reputação, onde ao fazer uma pergunta genuína, recebemos −30 na boca (Sabe, nem todo mundo é o gênio que vc é! Se não for ajudar não precisa tentar f***r com quem ta começando). Sem falar que quase todas às vezes que perguntei, me falaram para entrar no chat e perguntar, mas para entrar no chat e perguntar precisa de 20-30 de reputação, sabe porque é tão complicado conseguir ajuda daqui?
Enfim, só um desabafo, porque hoje foi F***!
att-  Até para postar isso estão me pedindo 1500 pontos haha, a ironia!
Sei que estou perdendo e que vão fazer eu deletar isso igual fizeram com todas as minhas perguntas anteriores, mas enfim é foi a minha terapia do dia

A comunidade existe para produzir conhecimento para os visitantes, não para dar ajuda particular, que é que descreveu. O primeiro passo é uma lida na [help], estudar bem o site. Depois de entender bem, fazer perguntas bem formuladas que sirvam para outras pessoas com o mesmo problema, dentro do objetivo. Aí serão bem aceitas. O que atrapalha novatos são postagens que aparecem nas buscas mas não trazem conhecimento. Não utilize o espaço para postagens que não cumpram a finalidade. Tem um quadrinho amarelo na página com orientações importantes em destaque, sugiro uma boa lida.

Não é um site de ajuda , é um site que visa melhores códigos, já até fiz perguntas aqui mas não é site para ajudar uma pessoa mas sim ajudar uma comunidade. Talvez falte um site de "me ajude" o "finado" Forum Imasters  era menos seletivo em suas perguntas hoje agoniza ... Hoje aqui só pergunto quando a coisa pode ser mesmo relevante e ao segundo "menos" já apago sem sequer discutir. Responder também é rarosó comento. Mas tem uma filosofia e esta deve ser seguida, ponto.
